# Do I glue the screw when mounting the PCB to enclosure or not?

Tags: pcb, enclosure, glue

Well, this is a handheld device we are developing at our firm. We bought the enclosure from a chinese man. in AliExpress. It's made out of ABS. The device is going to be used in an industrial site. The board pictured below is a UPS-like board that charges the battery and will have an adapter jack. Here are the PCB board mounting requirements:

1. Fastening the board so that it does not release in case of free fall or using extra force by personell while pluging the charging adapter.
2. Being able to quickly replace the board with a new one in case of component failure.

I intended to use glue inside the screw hole and tried CA and SR based adhesives, but they are uselss. CA-based glue is rigid and SR-based glue is not that hard.

What would you suggest?

[image]

Comment: typically you would use threadlocker in this situation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-locking_fluid

Comment: I would use a self-tapping screw of the right size to cut its own threads in the mounting holes.  An ordinary machine screw of the right size may work.

Comment: I still don’t understand the problem. Is the PCB loose after screwing it down?  Or does the screw not fit for some reason?  Can you elaborate on the problem and the need for glue?

Comment: @joemac Screw fits but if for some reasons ( mentioned above ) we push it, the screw loose.